# UIImageView with stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth doesn't stretch image

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, stretch

I'm trying to stretch an Image in a UIImageView - but I fail miserably :)

Following setup:

NIB-File with a view and a UIImageView attached to this view.

Wired to my class using `IBOutlet UIImageView *background`.

Now, in my class I try the following:

```
UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:50];
[background setImage: bgImage];

bgFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 200);
background.frame = bgFrame;
```

which should stretch the image vertically - at least, that's what I thought. Alas, it's not working... :(

The image I'm using has a height of 115px (which should be enough for the stretch, I guess?)

Answer (score 16):

Got it... (interesting that this happens often just seconds after asking the question)

In IB, I had to set the mode in the UIImageView to «Scale to fill» and set the Autoresize-property

That's what solved the problem...

Hope that helps somebody ;)

Comment: Yes, this helped me.  Thank you for posting your solution.  This must just be occurring in the new iOS versions as I never experienced the issue on earlier releases.  Mark it as the answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it depends on the file, However I did two things to fix it and I don't know which was the solution:

- Open and resave the file (I don't think this made the difference)
- Create the file.png and file@2x.png file. (Anyway this should always be done with stretchable images)

After I added the @2x file the image stretched ok.

Comment: I concur, Retina devices (and the simulator when set to Retina devices) don't stretch when falling back to a non-retina bitmap.