# Stretching an ellipse made of bezier curves to fit view bounds

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, geometry, core-graphics

I've created a special ellipse in illustrator, one that I need drawn in my app. I've used Qwarkee to convert it to core graphics code using mainly:

```
void CGPathAddCurveToPoint (CGMutablePathRef path, const CGAffineTransform *m, CGFloat cp1x, CGFloat cp1y, CGFloat cp2x, CGFloat cp2y, CGFloat x, CGFloat y);
```

Here is the code:

```
CGMutablePathRef pPath_0 = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 515.98,258.24);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 515.98,435.61,415.54,515.98,258.24,515.98);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 100.94,515.98,0.50,435.61,0.50,258.24);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 0.50,80.86,100.94,0.50,258.24,0.50);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pPath_0, NULL, 415.54,0.50,515.98,80.86,515.98,258.24);
CGPathCloseSubpath(pPath_0);
```

[image]

The diameter of the this proportionally sized ellipse is 515.98. Now I'd like to change the code so that the ellipse will be stretched to fit my view bounds no matter what size it is. The end points are obvious, I can just use the height and width of view to determine this. However, I'm having trouble understanding how I should determine the control points. Do I take these as proportions of view height / view width? Not sure I quite understand the mathematics of bezier paths so I can maintain the same amount of curve I've implemented as the view stretches either horizontally or veritcally.

Comment: Have you tried using `CGContextScaleCTM()` to scale the entire context?  I believe that would allow you to keep all of your drawing as-is; you'd just pass in the proportion of the width/height that you assumed versus the width/height that the view actually has.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to stretch the mutablePath instead? @KevinGrant

Comment: "Do I take these as proportions of view height / view width?" Well, what happens if you just try that?  (Hint: it should work just fine.)

Comment: @CoDEFRo I don't think you can scale the path, you either apply a transform to each element as you add it (the `NULL` parameters in all your calls above) or you scale the context before you draw something.

Comment: You can scale the path after the fact by applying a scale transform using `CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath` or `CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath`. Should be equivalent to the two ways that @KevinGrant mentioned.

Comment: @KurtRevis - Thanks Kurt that did work. Do you want to write that up as an answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471490/stretch-drawn-shape-to-fit-frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross posted this at a physics forum and a nice guy gave me a great solution:

http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?s=aff26efd9c911d2a8c29118f550b86fb&p=3996775#post3996775